# Как слушать все touch events приложения?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, cocoa

Есть задача - слушать все `touch events` и, при определенном количестве таких эвентов, выкидывать нотификацию; как следует реализовать такой функционал?
Пример метода слушателя:

```
var counter = 0
func listener(events: UIEvent) {
  if counter == 10 {
    NSNotificationCenter.post....
  }

  counter++
}
```

Comment: чего только люди не придумают... вообще все тачи? на всех скринах в любых точках?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Например тачи для всех UIControls

Comment: нет времени написать полный ответ, но идея в целом такая: вам надо как можно раньше в приложении (желательно в appDelegate) заменить `- touchesBegan:withEvent:` в UIResponder на свой метод, который будет считать тачи, и потом уже вызывать родной `touchesBegan:`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko спасибо, а как из всех тачей отсеять только те, что по кнопкам?

Comment: попробовать тот же фокус, но на уровне UIButton (не уверен, что получится, возможно UIButton не переопределяет этот метод). Либо если это все ваши кнопки сделать свой сабкласс, если это не ваши кнопки, то можно попробовать сделать категорию на UIButton и в ней переопределить touchesBegan: (эпл очень не рекомендует так делать, но попробовать можно)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko можете оформить комбинацию этих ответов)

Comment: так что то получилось?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да, после того, как я написал дополнительный вопрос, начал копать по нему и нашел)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

идея в целом такая: вам надо как можно раньше в приложении (желательно в appDelegate) заменить `- touchesBegan:withEvent:` в UIResponder на свой метод, который будет считать тачи, и потом уже вызывать родной touchesBegan:

если надо сделать только для UIButton: попробовать тот же фокус, но на уровне UIButton (не уверен, что получится, возможно UIButton не переопределяет этот метод). Либо если это все ваши кнопки сделать свой сабкласс, если это не ваши кнопки, то можно попробовать сделать категорию на UIButton и в ней переопределить touchesBegan: (эпл очень не рекомендует так делать, но попробовать можно)